# Series expansion of expectation

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces, expected-value

I have a bounded, integer values random variable $X_n$ which lies between $0$ and $n$. I want to find the expectation of $\frac{1}{X_n+1}$.

I want to say that $E[\frac{1}{X_n+1}] = \sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^jE[X_n^j]$, but I am worried about the convergence of this.

$\frac{1}{x+1}$ converges for $|x| < 1$, but it is not true that $E[X_n^j] = E[X_n]^j$, so I am unable to determine if finite moments is enough for convergence of the expectation of the fraction in question

Comment: The series will in general not converge (for example, if $X_n$ is any nonzero constant). What kind of expression for $E[(1+X_n)^{-1}]$ are you looking for? Does it need to be in terms of the moments of $X_n$? You can certainly write $E[(1+X_n)^{-1}]=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k+1}P(X_n=k)$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest because $X_n$ is a sum of very covariate indicators, computing explicit probabilities is difficult. It is much easier to compute polynomial expectations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the equation $1/(1+X)=\int_0^1 s^X\,ds$, we have
\begin{align}
E\left[\frac1{X+1}\right]
  &=E\left[\int_0^1s^X\,ds\right]
\\&=E\left[\int_0^1(1+(s-1))^X\,ds\right]
\\&=E\left[\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^n(s-1)^k\binom{X}k\,ds\right]
\\&=\sum_{k=0}^nE\left[\binom{X}k\right]\int_0^1(s-1)^k\,ds
\\&=\sum_{k=0}^nE\left[\binom{X}k\right]\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k+1}
\end{align}
Now, how is this helpful? Well, you mentioned that $X=Y_1+Y_2+\dots+Y_n$ is a sum of indicators. This means that
$$
\binom{X}k=\sum_{1\le i_1< i_2< \dots< i_k\le n}Y_{i_1}Y_{i_2}\cdots Y_{i_k}
$$
so $E[\binom{X}k]$ is the sum over all $k$-wise intersections of the probability that that intersection occurs. 
$$
E\left[\binom{X}k\right]=\sum_{1\le i_1< i_2< \dots< i_k\le n}P(Y_{i_1}=Y_{i_2}=\cdots =Y_{i_k}=1)
$$
I imagine these probabilities are somewhat natural to compute in the context of your problem.

Comment: This is so wonderfully elegant... i absolutely love this. The thing is that those probabilities are not so easy to compute: the indicators are probabilities that a vertex in an erdos-renyi random graph $G_{n,p}$ are less than degree 2 (degree 0 or 1). I can compute a lower bound for $E[\binom{X}{k}]$ by using FKG... would there be a way to get an upper bound?

Comment: Thank you for the kind words! I am out of my depth when it comes to random graphs. You might want to consider re-asking your comment as a separate question.